# Dotted line for answering a question with asciidoc

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor-pdf

I'm looking for a macro in asciidoc to fill some dot for answering a question in an exam, for example.

```
Firstname ................
```

Latex has something called \fillin or \dotfill , I'm looking for the same thing.

I use asciidoctor-pdf to render my asciidoc.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's no built-in feature in Asciidoctor but you can write a block extension:

```
[form]
First name
Last name
Age
```

The extension will compute how many dots is needed to fill each line and create a paragraph with the result.
When using an HTML backend, the result might look like:

```html
<p>
First name .....<br/>
Last name ......<br/>
Age ............<br/>
</p>
```

You could also add an option to configure the character used to fill the line:

```
[form,fill=_]
```

In this case it would produce:

```html
<p>
First name _____<br/>
Last name ______<br/>
Age ____________<br/>
</p>
```

If you've never written an Asciidoctor extension before, you can have a look at: https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-extensions-lab/blob/9efe18673cf5eca79f4121755e043effeddd7cd3/lib/shout-block/extension.rb